# mysql error when creating new stored procedure

Tags: mysql

simple question
this is the code to creat a simple stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$


CREATE  PROCEDURE `check_mobile_sp`(
  IN mobile_numberEntered VARCHAR(12)
)
BEGIN

  SELECT id, mobile_number, `date`
  from users
   WHERE mobile_number = mobile_numberEntered;


END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

and this is the error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1

Comment: How are you trying to run this statement?

Comment: by clicking go in the mysql phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

try placing // instead of $$:

```
DELIMITER //


CREATE  PROCEDURE `check_mobile_sp`(
  IN mobile_numberEntered VARCHAR(12)
)
BEGIN

  SELECT id, mobile_number, `date`
  from users
   WHERE mobile_number = mobile_numberEntered;


END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 11
STR: //
SQL: DELIMITER //

Comment: keep the $$ and remove the Delimiter word at the end of the query

Comment: got this #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$' at line 11

Comment: it is just a syntax error, can you send me the query? try adding ; at the end of the query